# What's the difference between Uri.ToString() and Uri.AbsoluteUri?

Tags: c#, .net

As a comment to an Azure question just now, @smarx noted

> I think it's generally better to do blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri than
>   blob.Uri.ToString().

Is there a reason for this? The documentation for `Uri.AbsoluteUri` notes that it "Gets the absolute URI", `Uri.ToString()` "Gets a canonical string representation for the specified instance."

Comment: ToString does make the URI more readable but while doing so, it decodes many URLEncoded characters which will be troublesome in some cases. The behavior is also different between runtimes of the .net framework.
See https://dhvik.blogspot.com/2019/12/uritostring-automatically-decodes-url.html for a comparison.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Given for example:

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("http://somehost/somepath");
builder.Query = "somekey=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("some+value");
Uri someUri = builder.Uri;
```

In this case,
`Uri.ToString()` will return a human-readable URL: http://somehost/somepath?somekey=some+value

`Uri.AbsoluteUri` on the other hand will return the encoded form as HttpUtility.UrlEncode returned it: `http://somehost/somepath?somekey=some%2bvalue`

Comment: But note that the "human-readable URL" (returned from ToString) is probably corrupted and almost never what you want: http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/08/uritostring_must_die.html. I would avoid calling ToString whenever possible.

Comment: There are times you do want ToString. Here in SO is a great example (See my answer above). You want to "visualize" the URL. The point (always in programming) is - be careful, and know what you are doing.

Comment: Note that the example here (and in http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/08/uritostring_must_die.html) are no longer current. These issues have been fixed in .NET Framework 4.5. However, ToString() is still only meant for human readable (visual) representation of the URL. If you copy this URL to the browser, it should still work.

Comment: Looks like it is best to use `OriginialString` than `ToString()` [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.originalstring?view=netframework-4.8#examples]

Answer (score 35):

*Additionally:* If your `Uri` is a **relative** `Uri` `AbsoluteUri` will fail, `ToString()` not.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("fuu/bar.xyz", UriKind.Relative);
string str1 = uri.ToString(); // "fuu/bar.xyz"
string str2 = uri.AbsoluteUri; // InvalidOperationException
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not check and use the correct one?

```
string GetUrl(Uri uri) => uri?.IsAbsoluteUri == true ? uri?.AbsoluteUri : uri?.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Since everybody seems to think that `uri.AbsoluteUri` is better, but because it fails with relative paths, then probably the universal way would be:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("fuu/bar.xyz", UriKind.Relative);
string notCorruptUri = Uri.EscapeUriString(uri.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

The following example writes the complete contents of the Uri instance to the console. In the example shown,

http://www.cartechnewz.com/catalog/shownew.htm?date=today

is written to the console.

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.cartechnewz.com");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "catalog/shownew.htm?date=today");
Console.WriteLine(myUri.AbsoluteUri);
```

The AbsoluteUri property includes the entire URI stored in the Uri instance, including all fragments and query strings.

Comment: And what does Uri.ToString do different?