# Uri ToStrings breaks %26 (&)

Tags: .net, uri

It blew my mind when I found that Uri tostring breaks uris.... Here is an example

If you run this in immediate mode you'd get

```
new Uri("http://site.com?a=1&b=c%26d").AbsoluteUri
```

Res

```
"http://site.com/?a=1&b=c%26d"
```

But

```
new Uri("http://site.com?a=1&b=c%26d").ToString() //string.format i believe doesn't need .ToString()
```

Gets me

```
"http://site.com/?a=1&b=c&d"
```

The b value is completely broken. I was shocked. Am I never to use `ToString()`? This seems like a bug. But writing this question gave me the answer (`.AbsoluteUri`). But maybe this will help someone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Uri.ToString() and Uri.AbsoluteUri?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624987/whats-the-difference-between-uri-tostring-and-uri-absoluteuri)

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, but [others](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/08/uritostring_must_die.html) [were](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2008/04/uriabsoluteuri-and-uritostring-are-not.html). Unless you are looking for another answer, you should post and accept your solution as an answer to close this question.

Comment: @Christian.K Guffa gave a fantastic answer. Better then my just use AbsoluteUri

Comment: Yep, I would agree with that ;-)

Comment: ToString does make the URI more readable but while doing so, it decodes many URLEncoded characters which will be troublesome in some cases. The behavior is also different between runtimes of the .net framework.
See https://dhvik.blogspot.com/2019/12/uritostring-automatically-decodes-url.html for a comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Uri.ToString` method isn't useful for anything other than to display the URI in a human friendly way.

From the code example on the [documentation for Uri.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx):

```
// The following outputs "http://www.contoso.com/thick and thin.htm".
Console.WriteLine(uriAddress.ToString());

// The following outputs "HTTP://www.Contoso.com:80/thick%20and%20thin.htm".
Console.WriteLine(uriAddress.OriginalString);
```

The example shows that the `ToString` method returns a string with spaces, which is not a character that is valid in an URI. The string representation of the Uri is clearly not intended to be used as an actual URI. This fact should perhaps be made more clearly in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

*I originally overlooked the fact that no escaping will help with the '&' symbol in @acidzombie24's example. 
I would have downvoted my answer if I could ;-P. Since I can't, I have edit it accordingly*

---

Note that [`Uri.EscapeUriString Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx) will not help in @acidzombie24's case, despite this sentence from MSDN:

> Use the EscapeUriString method to prepare an unescaped URI string to
>   be a parameter to the Uri constructor.

The documentation actualy hints on method's limitations:

> [Uri.EscapeUriString(stringToEscape)] method assumes that stringToEscape has no escape sequences in it.

---

**EDIT 2**
I tried to duplicate @acidzombie24's example in VS2012 WinForms app targeting 4.5, but 
`new Uri("http://site.com?a=1&b=c%26d").ToString()` returned the escaped version:
[image]