# Query parameters are not fully URL encoding

Tags: c#, url, restsharp

While using RestSharp (107.3.0) I've encountered a hurdle with it's URL encoding. My code is spread across several classes but looks something like this...

```
var student = new Student()
{
   Code = "123456",
   Name = "CABEÇA, ANNA",
   CourseCode = "CRS00199",
   Enrolled = "2022-07-27 12:25:57"
};

var clientOptions = new RestClientOptions()
{
   BaseUrl = new Uri("https://myapi")
};

var client = new RestClient(clientOptions);

var request = new RestRequest("student/{c}", Method.Put);
request.AddUrlSegment("c", student.Code);
request.AddQueryParameter("n", student.Name);
request.AddQueryParameter("cc", student.CourseCode);
request.AddQueryParameter("e", student.Enrolled);

var url = client.BuildUri(request);
```

This is working fine for 99.999% of the students, but for some with non-ASCII characters in their names, like the above (fake) student, the query parameters are not fully encoded within the resulting URL.

```
https://myapi/student/123456?n=CABEÇA%2c ANNA&cc=CRS00199&e=2022-07-27 12%3a25%3a57
```

I would expect the Ç in the student's name to be encoded as %c7.

Is there a "better" way to be doing this? Have I missed something obvious? I also see that spaces aren't being encoded, but commas, periods, and colons are.

Many thanks.

--- Update following Magnetron's answer ---
In a calling class, I was actually doing a ToString() on the returned Uri.

Comment: Use `url.AbsoluteUri` instead of `url.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be it. I hadn't realised that ToString() on a Uri was actually un-encoding some characters. I would have been digging around in RestSharp configurations settings for days.

Comment: Yeah, I found that odd too that `ToString` is a mix of encoded and unencoded. It would make more sense if it was all encoded or all unencoded, maybe it's some sort of backwards compatibility, don't really know.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about RestSharp but `Uri` implementation. Use `url.AbsoluteUri` instead of `url.ToString()` to get the desired encoded url.

From the [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-uri-tostring) documentation:

> The unescaped canonical representation of the Uri instance. All characters are unescaped except #, ?, and %.

See also [What's the difference between Uri.ToString() and Uri.AbsoluteUri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624987/whats-the-difference-between-uri-tostring-and-uri-absoluteuri)